# Does android:scaleType="fitCenter" only work with fix Layout_width and Layout_height attributes?

Tags: android, imageview, android-layout, android-image

I use  `Layout_width="fill_parent`" and `Layout_height="wrap content"`. If an image is bigger than the ImageView, it will be downscaled perfectly.

However, I never got it working to upscale smaller images. I tried any combination of [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) and "AdjustViewBounds": it always stays in its own size in the middle of the image view. Here is the code...

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/content_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1px">
        <ImageView
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/test"
          android:id="@+id/ImageViewTest"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true"
          android:scaleType="center"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try using CENTER_INSIDE or FIT_XY.

Comment: I tried all of them. None of them worked for me.

Comment: I found the only way to get it working, was setting layout_hight and layout_width to fixed values like 150dp x 200dp

Comment: I am not able to test the given answer(s) anymore, since I stopped developing Android Apps. Please suggest if I should mark an answer done, if you have tested it and matches the requirements of my question.

Answer (score 9):

I just found a way to make it work.

This works in 2.1(AVD) & 4.1.2(device)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: with this method, if you have a border on the imageView, there'll be whitespace on sides where the image didin't scale to

Answer (score 5):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

uses the original size of the image inside.

Try something bigger or fill_parent

Comment: This is just one of my golden answers, you have no idea of how much trouble I've had with imageview and its faulty (or misunderstood) scaletype. Thamls a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Use `android:scaleType="FIT_START"` or `android:scaleType="FIT_END"`, to Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst (from GoogleDev).

More info:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: It's android:scaleType="fitStart" or android:scaleType="fitEnd", and these are almost exactly the same as android:scaleType="fitCenter" anyway. The difference is how they handle the empty space, aliging to start, end, or centering.

Answer (score 1):

Adding  `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to ur ImageView should stretch the image if the size is small.

Comment: Yeah it works fine if image is larger but if its smaller then it only fits either height or width.  Stupid the way Android handles images